# ¿Como asignar un fieldName en un gridView desde un objeto que contiene una lista?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, telerik

Tengo un gridView con bastantes columnas, en cada una de ellas se especifica un FieldName.
Mi grid se llena directamente desde el momento en el que asigno el dataSource, ésto debido a que el objeto que asigno en el dataSource contiene campos con el mismo nombre que especifiqué en el FieldName de cada columna, el detalle está en que recientemente se asignó en el objeto un campo de tipo List del cual ocupo tomar el valor que se encuentra en la posición [0], es decir el primer registro de la lista, para lo cual agregué una nueva columna en el grid, sin embargo, no logro especificar de manera correcta en el FieldName el nombre del campo, lo intenté de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dato adicional el nombre de mi objeto principal (el que asigno al dataSource) se llama "_srcGrid" y dentro de él se encuentra la lista "Remisiones", cabe mencionar que no tengo problemas al asignar ningún otro campo del objeto en cualquier FieldName, el problema solo se presenta con esa lista.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Roberto Carlo, Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema). 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! 
Cuando respondas un comentario, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crea una propiedad en tu clase, algo así:

```
public class TransaccionComprobante{
  public string Moneda {get;set;}
//etc..El resto de las propiedades

  [NotMapped]
  public DateTime Fecha{ //el tipo de dato correspondiente
    get{
      //aquí sería bueno colocar algunas validaciones, como si el array Remisiones tiene algún dato
      return Remisiones[0].Fecha;
    }
  }
}
```

Luego en el `FieldName` pones `Fecha`

Comment: gracias por responder, también se me había ocurrido hacer eso sin embargo la aplicación trabaja con Entity framework y al modificar la entidad me arroja el siguiente error:
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'
Excepción interna
SqlException: Invalid column name 'Fecha'.
Invalid column name 'Fecha'.

Comment: @RobertoCarlo Y si le agregas el atributo `[NotMapped]` ???

Comment: Por alguna razón no puedo aplicar el atributo [NotMapped], desconozco la verdad si se deba a la versión de entity framework pero encontré algo similar, en mi clase de DataContext donde realizo el mapeo con la tabla simplemente apliqué:
Ignore(e => e.Fecha);
y funcionó correctamente :)
Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Yussef